# I merged instead of pulled, how to fix

Tags: git

I have a bit of a messy git tree and i was wondering the best way to fix it.

```
*   3f599ff - (HEAD, origin/enterprise-options, enterprise-options) Merge branch
|\
| * 5087bec - (upstream/master) Remote Change (2 days ago)
| * 6705b5f - Remote Change (2 days ago)
* | 880c0a6 - New Feature (3 hours ago)
|/
* 312968b - Blah (4 weeks ago)
```

I should have pulled in any changes before committing the new feature 880c0a6, but I didn't. I decided to merge upstream/master 5087bec. How can I revert the merge commit 3f599ff, pull changes and then recommit?

Or is this tree suitable as is? I'm contributing to an open source project and this is what my pull request currently looks like.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you haven't pushed to the remote repository, you can undo the merge and pull the changes.

```
git reset --hard 880c0a6
git pull --rebase
```

This will remove the remote commits and and reset your repo to your last local commit.  Then you can pull the changes with the `--rebase` option to have a linear history.  Only do this if your changes have NOT been pushed to the remote repo.  You are changing history and this is a bad practice.  You will have to do `git push -f` and anyone else that uses the remote will have trouble when updating from the remote

Otherwise a merge commit like that is generally harmless.

Comment: As long as this is only a local branch, `git pull --rebase` can in fact fix the whole problem. No need to `reset`.